# PHP looping increasing numbers

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have this code:

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=10)
  {
  echo "" . $i . "<br>";
  $i++;
  }
?>
```

This lists as:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

I'm trying to implement the `echo "" . $i . "<br>";` into a `<td>` cell in this:

```
<table>
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT board.*,numlikes FROM board
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pins.board_id, COUNT(source_user_id) AS numlikes
FROM likes INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = likes.pin_id GROUP BY pins.board_id) 
likes ON board.id = likes.board_id
WHERE who_can_tag='' ORDER BY numlikes DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data ))
{
Print "<tr>";
Print "<td>";
Print "$i";
Print "</td>";
Print "<td>";
Print "<a href='/board/index/".$info['id']."'><font size='5pt'>".$info['board_name']."</font></a>";
Print "</td>";
Print "<td align='center'>".$info['numlikes']."</td>";
Print "</tr>";

}

?>
</table>
```

But all I'm getting is the number 11 is every cell!

What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not setting the variable $i anywhere in the below code.

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php

Comment: To clarify a bit...specifically, the `mysql` extension (the one that provides the `mysql_` functions) is deprecated.  It has been in a maintenance-only phase, and hasn't been recommended for new code, for a number of years now anyway.  I'd demand a refund from whoever taught you to use it in 2013.

Comment: Do you mean the `mysql_query` part? Somebody told me recently on here that this was the latest way to go and that the one I had supplied in my question was deprecated.

Comment: There's a [comparison of the three MySQL APIs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) on the PHP website. mysql_* functions are deprecated; mysqli_* functions (and their object-oriented counterparts) are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not incrementing the variable in your `while loop`.

You need to declare `$i` and increment it in the loop, for instance:

```
$i = 1;
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data ))
{
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>";
   print "$i";
   print "</td>";
   print "<td>";
   print "<a href='/board/index/".$info['id']."'><font size='5pt'>".$info['board_name']."</font></a>";
   print "</td>";
   print "<td align='center'>".$info['numlikes']."</td>";
   print "</tr>";

   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about:

```
$i++;
```

line. And You have to set $i before while to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you nowhere increment `$i` in your second code. So increment it with `$i++`:

```
$i = 1;
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data ))
{
    // ...
    print "<td>";
    print $i++;
    print "</td>";
   //...
}
```

And also, initialize your `$i` first, so that you're sure that it wasn't set already before.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now. so simple, yet I've been mulling over this for hours.